# z-index not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dhtml

I have a button, while clicking the button i just produce a div containing some checkbox. If the user select the required checkbox, it will produce a iframe according to the value of the checkbox and the div will disappear. Its placed immediately below the button. Up to this its working fine.
If the user again click the button, the droping div is comes behind the frame. Please help me to make it visible above the frame. I have used z-index, its working in firefox - but i cant made it in IE..

Please help me regarding this.

Thanks
praveen j

Comment: What is your IE version?

Comment: i have tested i both IE 6 and IE 7

Answer (score 1):

There are known issues with IE and z-index. Which version of IE are you using firstly? Also does this help? It looks related, you may need to get your code up to get this resolved -> http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3337315.htm

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the zIndex of iFrame to a negative value when the div appears and the changing it to a positive one when the div disappears.

This might help you.

[INFO: How the Z-index Attribute Works for HTML Elements](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177378)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use

```
#layer
{
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

and then change it to visible and then again hidden, the following function changes css

```
function changecss(theClass,element,value) {
     var cssRules;
     var added = false;
     for (var S = 0; S < document.styleSheets.length; S++){
    if (document.styleSheets[S]['rules']) {
      cssRules = 'rules';
     } else if (document.styleSheets[S]['cssRules']) {
      cssRules = 'cssRules';
     } else {
      //no rules found... browser unknown
     }
      for (var R = 0; R < document.styleSheets[S][cssRules].length; R++) {
       if (document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].selectorText == theClass) {
        if(document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].style[element]){
        document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].style[element] = value;
        added=true;
        break;
        }
       }
      }
      if(!added){
      if(document.styleSheets[S].insertRule){
              document.styleSheets[S].insertRule(theClass+' { '+element+': '+value+'; }',document.styleSheets[S][cssRules].length);
            } else if (document.styleSheets[S].addRule) {
                document.styleSheets[S].addRule(theClass,element+': '+value+';');
            }
      }
     }
    }
```

call this function like this

```
javascript:changecss('#layer','visibility','visible');<br>
javascript:changecss('#layer','visibility','hidden');
```